# Connection ADF to cross-tenant Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl

I would like to connect to an Azure SQL Database using my Azure Data Factory. The Azure SQL Database is created on another tenant and has SQL authentication disabled.

Is there another option to connect to this Azure SQL Database than using a Service Principal?

I tried to connect using User Managed Instance and System Managed Instance, but this does not seem to work as the Azure SQL Database is on another tenant. SQL Authentication is also not an option.

Comment: As per [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq#can-i-use-a-managed-identity-to-access-a-resource-in-a-different-directorytenant) No. Managed identities don't currently support cross-directory scenarios. and you don't have SQL Authentication unable, so the option remains is **Service Principal** only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if the Azure SQL Database is in another tenant than ADF, then SQL Auth and Service principal auth are the only ways for the connectivity .
Managed identities are only leveraged for same tenant components.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Creating a Service Principal needs to happen by creating an "App Registration" on the Tenant of the Azure SQL DB?

Comment: Service principal needs to be created in the tenant tagged to the database. You are right on that aspect